# Validar un dato de tipo entero ingresado por el usuario en python

Tags: python, validación

```
numero=int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
if numero>=0 and numero <0:
    print("El numero es válido")
elif numero=="":
    print("La opción que ingreso no es un numero")
```

Saludos, como podria hacer para que cuando el usuario ingrese un dato de tipo caracter me sale el mensaje de "La opcion que ingresó no es un numero", no quiero que me salga el mensaje de error de consola, intente de esa manera, y con el elif not int(numero)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primero veamos por qué no funciona tu aproximación, tu primera línea es:

```
numero = int(input("Ingrese un numero:"))
```

`input()` pide una entrada al usuario y retorna siempre una cadena (`str`) que puede o no representar un entero. A continuación intentas convertir esa cadena a `int` mediante `int()`. Si el casting no es posible porque la cadena no representa un entero, se lanza una excepción en este mismo instante de tipo ValueError.

Si se lanza una excepción la ejecución termina en ese mismo punto, el resto de código no importa ya.

Si no hay una excepción, tu bloque `if - elif` tampoco sirve para nada, la condición:

```
if numero>=0 and numero <0:
```

no se cumplirá jamás, un entero no puede ser a la vez (`and`) mayor o igual que 0 y menor que 0. Igualmente

```
elif numero=="":
```

tampoco se va a cumplir nunca. Como se ha dicho `numero` o es un entero (`int`) o se lanza una excepción, jamás será una cadena en este punto dado que se ha llamado a `int()`, ni vacía ni con contenido.

Por otro lado usar:

```
elif not int(numero)
```

tampoco es una opción. Si se coloca en el código anterior, si no se produce la excepción en la primera línea el casting a `int` es redundante, pero además tenemos un problema:

- Si se ingresa un 0 `elif not 0` se cumple, dado que el 0 se evalúa como falso y el `not` lo niega.
- Si se ingresa cualquier otro número que no sea un 0 como `elif not 7` el `elif` no se cumple ya que cualquier entero que no sea 0 se evalúa como verdadero y el `not` lo niega.

Ahora bien, si en la primera línea no realizamos el casting a `int` y este solo tiene lugar en el `elif not int(numero)`, tampoco solucionamos nada. Al evaluar dicha expresión, primero se realiza la llamada a `int(numero)`, la cual como se ha dicho ocasionará una excepción si numero no representa un entero por lo que la ejecución termina ahí, no se aplica el `not` ni nada más. Ten en cuenta que un condicional no captura ni maneja una excepción. Si es un entero entonces se procede como hemos visto arriba con el tema del 0 o no 0.

La forma más común de resolver esto es simplemente manejar la excepción usando un bloque `try - except`:

```
    try:
        numero = int(input("Ingrese un número: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("La opción que ingreso no es un numero")
    else:
        print("El numero es válido")
```

En Python es común y aceptado usar el manejo de excepciones como mecanismo de control de flujo, por lo que el código anterior se considera generalmente el más "pitónico". No obstante hay quién considera esto un estilo erróneo, dado que no es un verdadero error, una situación excepcional, sino que es algo previsto de antemano y usado para controlar el flujo del programa y realmente en otros lenguajes es este el enfoque aceptado.... Hay muchas más formas de hacerlo, por ejemplo:

- Uso de `str.isdigit()`, comprobando si el primer carácter es `+` o `-`:

  ```
  numero = input("Ingrese un número: ")
  if numero.startswith("+") or numero.startswith("-"):
      if numero[1:].isdigit():
          print("El numero es válido")
      else:
          print("La opción que ingreso no es un numero")
  else:
      if numero.isdigit():
          print("El numero es válido")
      else:
          print("La opción que ingreso no es un numero")
  ```

  Se puede prescindir de los métodos de las cadenas y hacer las comprobaciones con `if  numero[0] in "+-":` y `if all(d in "0123456789" for d in numero)` por ejemplo.
- Uso de expresiones regulares:

  ```
  import re


  PATT = re.compile(r"[-+]?\d+$")
  numero = input("Ingrese un número: ")
  if PATT.match(numero) is None:
      print("La opción que ingreso no es un número")
  else:
      print("El número es válido")
  ```

Una vez validada la cadena por el método que sea (siempre que ésta sea correcta y coincida con lo que `int()` espera) puedes hacer el casting a `int` sin miedo a la excepción.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo,es bueno despejarme de estas dudas ya que asi aclaro mas mis ideas y entiendo mejor el funcionamiento de Python :)